# call ClojureScript from Javascript

Tags: javascript, clojure, clojurescript

How to call ClojureScript code from Javascript (*not* the other way around !).

It is already possible to [call Clojure from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181774/calling-clojure-from-java), but I don't know how to do the equivalent in ClojureScript.

Comment: Read this https://clojurescript.org/reference/advanced-compilation#access-from-javascript

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Export the functions you want to have available in js by using `^:export`, then simply call it as `my.ns.fn()`

cljs:

```
(ns hello-world.core)

(defn ^:export greet [] "Hello world!")
```

js:

```
hello_world.core.greet()
```

See [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26935889/1389573) to 
["Clojurescript interoperability with JavaScript"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26935101/clojurescript-interoperability-with-javascript) for detailed info.

Comment: As of 2020, `^:export` is redundant.

Answer (score 8):

Clojurescript compiles to Javascript so you can use it as is.

[Datascript](https://github.com/tonsky/datascript) is a great source of inspiration to learn this, it is written in Clojurescript and is used via [vanilla javascript](https://github.com/tonsky/datascript#using-from-vanilla-js) javascript as is.

In pseudo code that gives:

```
<script src="https://github.com/tonsky/datascript/releases/download/0.11.6/datascript-0.11.6.min.js"></script>
...
...
var d = require('datascript');
// or 
// var d = datascript.js;

var db = d.empty_db();
var db1 = d.db_with(db, [[":db/add", 1, "name", "Ivan"],
                       [":db/add", 1, "age", 17]]);
var db2 = d.db_with(db1, [{":db/id": 2,
                        "name": "Igor",
                        "age": 35}]);

var q = '[:find ?n ?a :where [?e "name" ?n] [?e "age" ?a]]'; 
assert_eq_set([["Ivan", 17]], d.q(q, db1));
assert_eq_set([["Ivan", 17], ["Igor", 35]], d.q(q, db2));
```

You can see the interop section of this [blog entry](http://tonsky.me/blog/datascript-internals/#javascript-interop).

Lastly, go through the datascript j[avascript-based test suite](https://github.com/tonsky/datascript/blob/master/test/js/tests.js).

Comment: Thank you that was useful, especially this: https://github.com/tonsky/datascript/blob/18ab268d4682f2ef0c75ce42548494726009f82f/src/datascript/js.cljs#L62